# Fedex Shipping Not Working Magento 1.9 CE

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, fedex

I have an installation of Magento 1.9.1.1 and have Fedex Web Services set up.  Fedex has verified that the account is setup correctly and that I have the correct credentials.  All of my store addresses match the addresses on my fedex account exactly.

I am directly copy n pasting the Account ID, Key, Meter Number, and Production Password into Magento and when I attempt a checkout, it says shipping method not available.   I am attempting a sample order from a USA address to a USA address.

Please help! It is very appreciated!  (Note: I'm not using any extensions that affect shipping or anything like that and shipping weights have been added to products)

Here are screenshots of the shipping settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: use this http://www.cobbconsulting.net/magento-fedex-setup.html

Comment: I'd actually read over that guide before but re-reading it allowed me to figure out the issue.

I had it set to "Regular Pickup" with the idea that the client was able to have FedEx do a daily pickup, apparently that isn't setup yet.  I set it to Business Service Center and it's up and running.  

Thanks!

Comment: Was facing the same problem. I figured out that the web services url was blocked in my office. I went home and carried out the process from different network and Voila ! It worked smoothly

Answer (score 0):

1- Try using Sandbox Mode = Yes. It's weird, I know, but it works sometimes.

2- Set Debug = Yes to view the logs in `/var/log/` and see what's going on.

Comment: My credentials correct, i have two store in single magento, store 1 display Fedex shipping cost, but store 2 not displaying shipping cost, how can i solve this issue?